# Foreach sends email for every loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, phpmailer

I have a PHP foreach loop that runs through an email cue and sends an email.
My problem is that it send an email to every mail from the cue for every row in the cue, so lets say there are 50 mails in the cue, I will get 50 emails. Not cool

The foreach is this:

```
$cue = new NewsletterHandler;       
$cue->GetEmailCue($letter_id, $lhash);

require_once(INCLUDE_DIR."/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From     = "tegl@xxxxxxx";
$mail->FromName = "Randers Tegl";
$mail->Host     = "smtp.xxxxx.dk";
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";

foreach($cue->email_row as $key => $value) { 
   $mail->AddAddress($value);
   $mail->Subject = $subject ." - ". date("d-m-Y");
   $mail->Body    = $this->htmlTemplate;    

   if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "E-mailen er ikke sendt til ". $value;
      echo "Mailer Error: ". $mail->ErrorInfo;
      echo "<br />";
      mail("morten@domain.dk", "Error", "Letter not send. ". $mail->ErrorInfo ."");
   } else {
      $sql_update = "UPDATE newsletter_emailcue SET time_recieved = NOW() WHERE email = '". $value ."'";
      SQLHandling::SQLquery($sql_update);    
      echo "Newsletter send to ". $value ."<br />"; 
   }
}
```

GetEmailCue function:

```
function GetEmailCue($letter_id, $lhash) {

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM newsletter_emailcue WHERE mail_to_recieve = '". $letter_id ."' AND time_recieved = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' LIMIT 50";
       $result = SQLHandling::SQLquery($sql);

       if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
            Main::txtOutput("Der er ikke nogle modtagere til nyhedsbrevet", "TXT_ERR");

           /*** If there aren't any emails in the cue table, but a pending letter was found
           * that letter will be updated with '2' in status, which is send completed.
           */
           $sql_update = "UPDATE newsletter_items SET status = 2 WHERE letter_id = '". $letter_id ."'";
          SQLHandling::SQLquery($sql_update);
       } else {              
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
               $this->email_row[] = $row["email"];
           }
      }

            return $this->email_row;
       }
```

if I `var_dump($cue->email_row) outside the foreach` I get `array(2) { [0]=> string(17) "morten@domain1.dk" [1]=> string(14) "morten@domain2.dk" }` but inside I get

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(17) "morten@adomain1.dk" [1]=> string(14) "morten@domain2.dk" } 
array(2) { [0]=> string(17) "morten@domain1.dk" [1]=> string(14) "morten@domain2.dk" }
```

Comment: It won't really help you with your question, but a "waiting line" is pronounced `queue`, not `cue`.

Comment: You seem to want to start receiving more spam than you already have because you are so happily show your email addresses....

Comment: @loler I removed some that looked like valid ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! I forgot to put

```
$mail->ClearAddresses();
$mail->ClearAttachments();
```

at the end of the script, so it was inserting every mail when running through `$mail->AddAddress($value);`

Answer (score 0):

few things :

- you might send one mail in BCC mode (blind copy) so no one receiver get all the other mailing list of emails
- you might operate sql update outside of a loop (multi update with , separating), build one big sql query string and execute it one after the loop so you save some heavy many SQL access, (try with 10000 different updates or once for 10000 records)
- you might ALWAYS escape SQL the variables used in the query (ie:$letter_id) coming from outside the scope (so you never know if it is safe of not) or you will be vulnerable to sql injection
- then about what you var_dump : don't see for the moment, where are placed the var_dump in the code ?